# Web form Azure Active directory : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-active-directory

I have a web site (web form, entity framework) and I use AAD connection.
I did modifications following this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/)

Problem, scripts and css are not loaded.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 () for base.css, jquery-3.1.1.min.js...

I put authentication mode in my web.config and in IIS, I disable all authentication (Anonymous, windows...).

I gave full control rights on the project folder.

Then for testing, I set enable the anonymous authentication, restart the site and it works. Then I open another browser and I have the same ugly formatting. I don't understand. It looks like it works once and then no.

Can you help me. Should I change something in IIS? Something else?

Thank you.

**Update** : I put a technical user have rights on the project folder on the app pool identity but it takes the azure ad users and they haven't rights on this folder. How can I force to use my technical user after any azure ad user connect to the web site?

Comment: are you using Owin library?

Comment: I used Owin library but I finally deploy my site directly into Azure Web App.

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Based the information you provided if you are using AAD then The issue for sure is with the "Authentication / Authorization" to getting resources,if you use the **`Owin`** library alongside Azure AD it maybe happens when you use manually access token to sand and somehow this access token is not accepted.

**2-**

please double check configuration data for Web Api. it should be look likes this but based your parameters:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "myportal.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "mytenant-guid",
    "ClientId": "https://myportal.onmicrosoft.com/test_core_web_api_spa"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get CSS/static resources? If they're under authentication, then I doubt Chrome (or whatever other browser) would know how to authenticate using `OWIN`.

Which explains why you can get them anonymously.

It sounds like OWIN is authentication the XHR requests, but chrome is trying to access assets directly - and doesn't send the correct auth, hence 401.